# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to create 2 table in a database, but I get next sintax errors:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapplication/com.myapplication.MyActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Details": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Activities Details(id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Activities(id), heartRate INTEGER, heartBeatNo INTEGER, Distance INTEGER, Speed INTEGER, Strides INTEGER,CurrentDateTime TEXT)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Details": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Activities Details(id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Activities(id), heartRate INTEGER, heartBeatNo INTEGER, Distance INTEGER, Speed INTEGER, Strides INTEGER,CurrentDateTime TEXT)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
            at com.myapplication.DatabaseHandler.onCreate(DatabaseHandler.java:74)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.myapplication.DatabaseHandler.addActivity(DatabaseHandler.java:98)
            at com.myapplication.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 05:53:49.484      947-947/com.myapplication D/Insert:﹕ Inserting . .
07-29 05:53:49.584      947-947/com.myapplication E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "Details": syntax error
07-29 05:53:49.614      947-947/com.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-29 05:53:49.624      947-947/com.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
07-29 05:53:49.644      947-947/com.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapplication/com.myapplication.MyActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Details": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Activities Details(id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Activities(id), heartRate INTEGER, heartBeatNo INTEGER, Distance INTEGER, Speed INTEGER, Strides INTEGER,CurrentDateTime TEXT)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Details": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Activities Details(id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Activities(id), heartRate INTEGER, heartBeatNo INTEGER, Distance INTEGER, Speed INTEGER, Strides INTEGER,CurrentDateTime TEXT)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
            at com.myapplication.DatabaseHandler.onCreate(DatabaseHandler.java:74)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.myapplication.DatabaseHandler.addActivity(DatabaseHandler.java:98)
            at com.myapplication.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The first error seems to be in next line of code:

```
String CREATE_ACTIVITIES_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_ACTIVITIES_DETAILS + "(" +
            ACTIVITY_ID + " INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES " + 
            TABLE_ACTIVITIES + "(" + KEY_ID + "), " +
            KEY_HEARTRATE + " INTEGER, "+
            KEY_HEARTBEATNO + " INTEGER, "+
            KEY_DISTANCE + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_SPEED + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_STRIDES + " INTEGER," +
            KEY_CURRENTDATETIME + " TEXT" +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ACTIVITIES_DETAILS_TABLE);
```

Here is my DatabaseHandler class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "YastDB.com.yast.db";

// Activities table name
private static final String TABLE_ACTIVITIES = "Activities";
private static final String TABLE_ACTIVITIES_DETAILS = "ActivitiesDetails";

// Activities Table Col names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_ACTIVITYTYPE = "ActivityType";
private static final String KEY_STARTDATETIME = "StartDateTime";
private static final String KEY_ENDDATETIME = "EndDateTime";


//Activities details table col names
private static final String ACTIVITY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_HEARTRATE = "heartRate";
private static final String KEY_HEARTBEATNO = "heartBeatNo";
private static final String KEY_DISTANCE = "Distance";
private static final String KEY_SPEED = "Speed";
private static final String KEY_STRIDES = "Strides";
public static final String  KEY_CURRENTDATETIME = "CurrentDateTime";

private String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{ KEY_ID,
        KEY_ACTIVITYTYPE, KEY_STARTDATETIME,KEY_ENDDATETIME };

private String[] PROJECTIONDETAILS = new String[]{ ACTIVITY_ID,
        KEY_HEARTRATE, KEY_HEARTBEATNO, KEY_DISTANCE,
        KEY_SPEED,KEY_STRIDES,KEY_CURRENTDATETIME};

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_ACTIVITIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            KEY_ACTIVITYTYPE + " INTEGER,"+
            KEY_STARTDATETIME + " TEXT," +
            KEY_ENDDATETIME + " TEXT" +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ACTIVITIES_TABLE);

    String CREATE_ACTIVITIES_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES_DETAILS + "(" +
            ACTIVITY_ID + " INTEGER FOREIGHN KEY REFERENCES " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES + "(" + KEY_ID + "), " +
            KEY_HEARTRATE + " INTEGER, "+
            KEY_HEARTBEATNO + " INTEGER, "+
            KEY_DISTANCE + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_SPEED + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_STRIDES + " INTEGER," +
            KEY_CURRENTDATETIME + " TEXT" +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ACTIVITIES_DETAILS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES_DETAILS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
 }
```

}

The ActivityEntity's attributes and constructors are below. It has set/get methods for all theirs attributes

```
public class ActivityEntity {

//private variables

private int id;
private int activityType;
private String startDateTime;
private String endDateTime;

// Empty constructor
public ActivityEntity(){

}
// constructor
public ActivityEntity(int id, int activityType, String startDateTime, String endDateTime){
    this.id = id;
    this.activityType = activityType;
    this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
    this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
}

public ActivityEntity(int activityType,  String startDateTime, String endDateTime){
    this.activityType = activityType;
    this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
    this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
}
```

The ActivityDetails's attributes and constructors are below. It has set/get methods for all theirs attributes

```
 public class ActivityDetalis {

    //private variables

   private  int activityId;
   private int heartRate;
   private int heartBeatNo;
   private int distance;
   private int speed;
   private int strides;
   private String currentDateTime;
    // Empty constructor
    public ActivityDetalis() {
    }


    public ActivityDetalis(int activityId, int heartRate, int heartBeatNo, int distance, int speed, int strides, String currentDateTime) {
        this.activityId = activityId;
        this.heartRate = heartRate;
        this.heartBeatNo = heartBeatNo;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.strides = strides;
        this.currentDateTime = currentDateTime;
    }

    public ActivityDetalis(int heartRate, int heartBeatNo, int distance, int speed, int strides, String currentDateTime) {
        this.heartRate = heartRate;
        this.heartBeatNo = heartBeatNo;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.strides = strides;
        this.currentDateTime = currentDateTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space in your table name. Either remove the space, or put the table name in double quotes:

```
private static final String TABLE_ACTIVITIES_DETAILS = "ActivitiesDetails";
```

or

```
private static final String TABLE_ACTIVITIES_DETAILS = "\"Activities Details\"";
```

Comment: Either you didn't really change the code that was run, or the error message is not really the same. Please update the question if you're still seeing a problem.